# Cypress: How to test Windows window to Save a Data?

Tags: windows, testing, automated-tests, cypress

I have a test that opens a windows pop-up to save the users personal data. Here I want to click "OK"

I tried to use `cy.go('forward')` but that does not work for windows pop ups.

[image: Windows Window]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. add pictures to the fixtures folder
2. Install file-upload via powershell `npm install cypress-file-upload`
3. add to yout commands.js : `import ‘cypress-file-upload’`
4. add to your code:
   cy.xpath('//*[@id="FileUpload"]')
   .attachFile('/picturename')

Answer (score 0):

Change the download directory of files downloaded during Cypress tests.
[Change download directory cypress doc](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/browser-launch-api.html#Change-download-directory)

```
// cypress/plugins/index.js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = (on) => {
  on('before:browser:launch', (browser, options) => {
    const downloadDirectory = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'downloads')

    if (browser.family === 'chromium' && browser.name !== 'electron') {
      options.preferences.default['download'] = { default_directory: downloadDirectory }

      return options
    }

    if (browser.family === 'firefox') {
      options.preferences['browser.download.dir'] = downloadDirectory
      options.preferences['browser.download.folderList'] = 2

      // needed to prevent download prompt for text/csv files.
      options.preferences['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = 'text/csv'

      return options
    }
  })
}
```

Window doesn't open, and the file is downloaded directly. (It doesn't work for Electron browser)